# I need to run one single nest application with different entryFile but I got this error:

Tags: nestjs

cli command:

```
yarn run build 
yarn run start --entryFile=src/bull-ui.main.ts
```

console output:

```
    yarn run v1.22.21
$ nest start --entryFile=src/bull-ui.main.ts
Error: Cannot find module '/home/zee/Projects/raspina/backend_base/dist/src/bull-ui.main.ts'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

is there any way to do it without need to make the application monorepo? (and changing the folder structure)